# Moving ActiveX button code from a sheet to a module leaves the button useless. Need help to fix it

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA code that copy/pastes different cells within the same sheet, so I created an ActiveX button and pasted my code in the button's, which was automatically created in the sheet where my button is.

After a while, I needed to copy/paste within multiple sheets, so I tried to move my code to a Module, since otherwise some methods did not work (like Range). However, I do not know how to associate the button to this new code that I moved.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a button on each sheet that you would like to run the code in your module, have the automatically generated event handler(the myButton_click) call the code in your module like below.

In Microsoft Excel Objects  --> Sheet1 (Sheet1)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call mySub
End Sub
```

In Microsoft Excel Objects  --> Sheet2 (Sheet2)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call mySub
End Sub
```

In Modules --> Module1

```
Public Sub mySub
'my code
End Sub
```

Each sheet/button you would want to have its own event handler to call the code in your module (mysub).
Note the sub in your module will need to be public.
Note the sub in your module will need to use references like ActiveWorksheet.Range instead of just Range.

Comment: This works. However, I have noticed my code is slower and sometimes I have trouble saving my code. Thanks, though.

Comment: What "trouble" do you have saving? As far as slower, housing your code in a sub-routine and calling it is cheap. Perhaps you could optimize your new code using with statements.

Comment: "Trouble" is, I cannot save the document, I get an error just saying so.

I should learn the with statements; do you have a suggestion as  far as references go. Thanks again.

Comment: If you would like help with error, please provide the code that errors and the error message that you receive.